# Problem with document.removeEventListener()

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, addeventlistener

I have a function that creates an event listener:

```
document.addEventListener(name, handler.bind(null, name, callback), false);
```

I use .bind to pass the extra parameters, but when I try to remove it:

```
document.removeEventListener(name, handler, false);
// or
document.removeEventListener(name, handler.bind(null), false);
```

It **doesn't** actual get removed. I have tried various fixes and cannot seem to get it to work.

Comment: `bind()` creates a new function so references are not the same https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to save a reference to the bound function, so that `removeEventListener` can be called with it later:

```
const boundHandler = handler.bind(null, name, callback);
document.addEventListener(name, boundHandler, false);

// later:

document.removeEventListener(name, boundHandler, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

> The [`EventTarget.removeEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) method removes from the EventTarget an event listener previously registered with EventTarget.addEventListener(). ***The event listener to be removed is identified using a combination of the event type, the event listener function itself***, and various optional options that may affect the matching process.

As you are using [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind), The `bind()` method **creates a new function** that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

Hence while using `removeEventListener`, you are not passing same reference of the function which was added for `addEventListener`.

Have cached `Handler function` in a variable which could be used for the both, `addEventListener` as well as `removeEventListener`

```
let handlerFunction = handler.bind(null, name, callback);
document.addEventListener(name, handlerFunction, false);
document.removeEventListener(name, handlerFunction, false);
```